# Reason behind Arrays of Integer

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I found this code on the internet (because I'm trying to create a timer). Can someone tell me why this codes does not throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Here's the code:

```
hour = new int[30];
min = new int[30];
sec = new int[30];
msec = new int[30];
start = false;
stop = true;
for(int j = 0  ; j <= 30 ; j++)
{
    hour[j] = 0;
    min[j] = 0;
    sec[j] = 0;
    msec[j] = 0;
}
```

then it is rendered with a timer task

```
    public void run()
    {
        msec[count]++;
        if(msec[count] == 100)
        {
            msec[count] = 0 ;
            sec[count]++;
        }
        else if(sec[count] ==60)
        {
            sec[count] = 0;
            min[count]++;
        }
        else if(min[count] == 60)
        {
            min[count] = 0;
            hour[count]++;
        }
        else if(hour[count] == 24)
        {
            hour[count] = 0;
        } 
        repaint();
    } 
};
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,10,67);
```

Why is it not throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I am confused because it is instantiated with a value of 30 and when I try to run this the runningTime exceeeds to 30 like 100 in msec, 59 in sec so on and so forth.

And here's the full code:

```
 public class TimerCan extends Canvas
{
private Timer timer;
private Midlet myMid;
private Player z;
private int habaNgString,hour[],sec[],min[],msec[],maxX,maxY,count,length,x,y;
private String runningTime;
private boolean start,stop;
public Image img;
public TimerCan(Midlet midlet)
{
    this.myMid= midlet;
    try
    {
        maxX = getWidth();
        maxY = getHeight();
        count = 0;
        hour = new int[30];
        min = new int[30];
        sec = new int[30];
        msec = new int[30];
        start = false;
        stop = true;
        for(int j = 0  ; j <= 30 ; j++)
        {
            hour[j] = 0;
            min[j] = 0;
            sec[j] = 0;
            msec[j] = 0;
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
         if(hour[count] < 10)
        {
            runningTime = "0"+String.valueOf(hour[count])+":";
        }
        else
        {
            runningTime = String.valueOf(hour[count]) + ":";  
        }
        if(min[count] < 10)
        {
            runningTime = runningTime+"0"+String.valueOf(min[count]) + ":";
        }
        else
        {
            runningTime = runningTime+String.valueOf(min[count]) + ":";
        }
        if(sec[count] < 10)
        {
            runningTime = runningTime+"0"+String.valueOf(sec[count]) + ":";
        }
        else
        {
            runningTime = runningTime + String.valueOf(sec[count]) + ":";
        }
        if(msec[count] < 10)
        {
            runningTime = runningTime+"0"+String.valueOf(msec[count]);
        }
        else
        {
            runningTime = runningTime+String.valueOf(msec[count]);
        }

    try{
         img = Image.createImage("/picture/aa.png");
    }
    catch(Exception error){
    }
    x = getWidth()/2;
    y = getHeight()/2;
    g.setColor(63,155,191);
    g.fillRect(0,0,maxX, maxY);
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, Graphics.VCENTER|Graphics.HCENTER);
    g.setColor(0,0,0) ;                                               
    g.drawString(runningTime,maxX,maxY,Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
}
private void startTimer()
{
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
           msec[count]++;
            if(msec[count] == 100)
            {
                msec[count] = 0 ;
                sec[count]++;
            }
            else if(sec[count] ==60)
            {

                sec[count] = 0;
                min[count]++;
            }
            else if(min[count] == 60)
            {
                min[count] = 0;

               hour[count]++;
            }
            else if(hour[count] == 24)
            {
                hour[count] = 0;
            } 
                   repaint();
        } 
    };
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,10,67);           
}
protected  void keyPressed(int keyCode)
{
    if(keyCode == Canvas.KEY_NUM1)
    {
        if(start == false)
        {
            start=true;
            stop=false;
        }
        else if(stop == false)
        {
            start = false ;
            stop = true ;
            timer.cancel();
        }
        if(start==true)
        {
            startTimer();
        }
    }
    if(keyCode == Canvas.KEY_NUM2)
    {                 
        min[count]=0;
        sec[count]=0;
        msec[count]=0;       
        start = false;
        stop = true;
        timer.cancel();
        try{
        z.deallocate();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        repaint();
    }
    if(keyCode == Canvas.KEY_NUM3)
        {
            if(stop == false)
            {
            start = false;
            stop = true;
            timer.cancel();
            try{
                InputStream inss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("alarm.wav");
                InputStreamReader iis= new InputStreamReader(inss);  
                z = Manager.createPlayer(inss,"audio/x-wav");
                z.prefetch();
                z.setLoopCount(2);
                z.start();
                }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
            }
        }
    if(keyCode==Canvas.KEY_NUM0)
    {
        try{
        z.deallocate();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        myMid.exit();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Of course the first snippet does throw an exception. As for the rest, we have no idea without seeing the rest of the code. (What is count?)

Comment: `for(int j = 0  ; j <= 30 ; j++)` should become `for(int j = 0  ; j < 30 ; j++)` because you can have 30 elements in your arrays but indexes are from 0 to 29

Comment: If your intent is to learn to write good Java code, I suggest throwing this example away. It might be useful if you want to learn how to fix up bad code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it *looks* like an exception is not thrown is because the code is terrible and catches the exception:

```
try
{
    maxX = getWidth();
    maxY = getHeight();
    count = 0;
    hour = new int[30];
    min = new int[30];
    sec = new int[30];
    msec = new int[30];
    start = false;
    stop = true;
    for(int j = 0  ; j <= 30 ; j++)
    {
        hour[j] = 0;
        min[j] = 0;
        sec[j] = 0;
        msec[j] = 0;
    }
}catch(Exception e)
{} // <- catches the exception and does nothing
```

Change the catch block to this:

```
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And you will see that an exception is thrown. Then you could either:

- A) Remove the try/catch and change `<= 30` to `< 30`.
- B) Discard the code because it's a poor example.

As for the block in `run`, as far as I can tell, count is never changed so it's always 0.

Comment: then if the count is always zero?, why i can see an incrementing numbers when i run these codes?

Comment: They are incrementing the int element in the array. `someArr[someInt]++`

Comment: if that's the case, what is the purpose of the for-loop in these code?

Comment: I have no idea. I tried to figure it out myself. As far as I can see count is always 0 so they don't need any arrays.

Comment: The for-loop is completely pointless.  It does nothing, other than throwing the exception on the last iteration.  This code was written by someone who doesn't understand Java very well.  Please don't try to learn from it.  And _never_ write `catch(Exception e){}`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Among other things, they also appear to load an Image from a file on every repaint.

Comment: Arrgh!  You're right.  I missed that on first reading.  Did this code come from a web site about bad practices, and what you shouldn't do in a Java program?

Comment: so, maybe i can remove this for-loop then declares this arrays in 0? or both remove these arrays and for-loop and declare and instantiate an integer in 0?

Comment: Just remove the for loop entirely.  Your integers will be zero, without any intervention from you.  And don't trust Java-programming strangers on the Internet!  (umm, forgetting that I am a ... )

Comment: @DavidWallace i don't know, i copied it about 3 weeks ago or more.

Comment: Also, does the programmer think that there are 100 milliseconds in a second?

Comment: @user3322668 As we are kinda discussing this code is just really bad. If you want to write something like this you should probably start from scratch. What they are doing with the arrays to keep track of a time increment is not only a little nutty to begin with but it is like a watch that's off. It depends on the accuracy of scheduleAtFixedRate. Java has classes like Date and Calendar if you want to make a clock widget.

Comment: Some useful links to do something like this the right way are [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [System.currentTimeMillis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
    hour = new int[30];
    min = new int[30];
    sec = new int[30];
    msec = new int[30];
    start = false;
    stop = true;
    for(int j = 0  ; j <= 30 ; j++)
    {
        hour[j] = 0;
        min[j] = 0;
        sec[j] = 0;
        msec[j] = 0;
    }
```

This code *will* through an IndexOutOfBounds exception. The final pass through the loop j is 30, the highest index in any array is 29.

If it isn't throwing an exception then this code is not being executed or the exception is being caught.